# How can we remove Google cloud builder cache. I am trying to build an image but it gives an error from a previous build attempt

Tags: docker, google-cloud-platform, cache, gcloud

This is the error it gives but the thing is I corrected the "MKDIR" command to mkdir but the error didn't go away, there is no MKDIR command in my Dockerfile anymore but the error stays the same. I deleted the repositories and even the project, changed directory too. Kindly guide me.

```
Operation completed over 1 objects/38.7 MiB.
BUILD
Already have image (with digest): gcr.io/cloud-builders/docker
Sending build context to Docker daemon  100.9MB
Error response from daemon: dockerfile parse error line 4: unknown instruction: MKDIR
ERROR
ERROR: build step 0 "gcr.io/cloud-builders/docker" failed: step exited with non-zero status: 1
```

Comment: You probably want to begin the line with RUN

Comment: Which line? I successfully built an image before with the same method. It worked then

Comment: Isn't there a command equivalent to docker builder prune in gcloud?